# Use of CTE (WITH) in a MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use CTE for running the query below to avoid the "can't reopen the table xxxx' error in a MySQL stored procedure. MySQL Workbench claims a syntax error and doesn't allow to save the procedure. WITH is underlined in red and reads

> "With" is not valid a this position for this server version (8.0.13), expecting : CACHE, CHECKSUM, COMMIT.....

```
        ELSE
            -- Board charges
            WITH cte AS (SELECT id FROM billablehorses)
            INSERT INTO billablehorses 
            (id, horse, agrid, dos, months, installment, totalamount, billed, payableid)
            SELECT ah.id, h.name, a.id, ah.dos, 
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, ah.dos, b.boardingdate) Months,
            p.amount,
            a.totalamount,
            TRUE,
            p.id
            FROM horses h 
            INNER JOIN agreementhorses ah
            ON h.id = ah.horseid
            INNER JOIN agreements a 
            ON ah.agreementid = a.id
            INNER JOIN payables p
            ON ah.id = p.agreementhorseid
            INNER JOIN boarding b
            ON p.ticketid = b.id
            WHERE p.typeid = 1
            AND ah.id IN (SELECT id FROM cte)
            AND EXISTS (SELECT id FROM billed WHERE id = ah.id);
            SET msg = CONCAT(ROW_COUNT() , " ", 'board charges inserted');
        END IF;
```

Comment: You would get this error even if you attempted the with as standalone code - you need a different approach.

Comment: Yes P.Salmon, I tried in a simple procedure with the same result. The documentation reads "A WITH clause is permitted : ..... At the beginning of subqueries (including derived table subqueries) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html - wich I also tried with no luck. Is it a bug?

Comment: I solved the issue by using a temporary table, but it would be nice to figure out why the CTE is not working in stored procedures - or maybe not in MYSQL Workbench

Comment: @Erick I have a SP working with a CTE in a subquery just fine, but the SP I'm troubleshooting now has a `insert into .... with ... select` syntax and it doesn't work. I also tried putting the CTE inside a subquery, like `insert into ... select * from ( with ... )`, still doesn't work. The query it runs executes in less than a second outside the SP.  Been debugging this for hours now, I'm at a loss. Any ideas? The SP always gets stuck at `statistics`.

Comment: I ruled out CTE being at fault - `insert into tbl  (col1, col2, ...) with cte as ( select 123, 456, ... ) select * from cte;` - this works inside a SP.